# Bitbucket Pull Request Builder plugin for Jenkins unable to post comments

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins

The Bitbucket Pull Request Builder plugin for Jenkins allows Jenkins build to be triggers when Pull requests are created or commented on in Bitbucket.

This has been working fine for us, but on one particular repo, it has started failing.

The logs show:

```
WARNING: bitbucketpullrequestbuilder.bitbucketpullrequestbuilder.BitbucketBuildTrigger.run() failed for hudson.model.FreeStyleProject@2840d594[ci-metadata-app-new]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at bitbucketpullrequestbuilder.bitbucketpullrequestbuilder.BitbucketRepository.postBuildTagInTTPComment(BitbucketRepository.java:182)
    at bitbucketpullrequestbuilder.bitbucketpullrequestbuilder.BitbucketRepository.isBuildTarget(BitbucketRepository.java:253)
    at bitbucketpullrequestbuilder.bitbucketpullrequestbuilder.BitbucketRepository.getTargetPullRequests(BitbucketRepository.java:94)
    at bitbucketpullrequestbuilder.bitbucketpullrequestbuilder.BitbucketPullRequestsBuilder.run(BitbucketPullRequestsBuilder.java:37)
    at bitbucketpullrequestbuilder.bitbucketpullrequestbuilder.BitbucketBuildTrigger.run(BitbucketBuildTrigger.java:187)
```

It looks like the plugin can't post a comment to the Bitbucket API

```
postBuildTagInTTPComment
```

Which is preventing the build from triggering.

Has anyone seen this issue before? It is only happening for this particular repo.

Comment: Does this repo have the same credentials as other?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually cleared it by deleting all the pull requests and adding them back one by one. I think it had something to do with one PR have a target branch that was behind its source branch.